# Laravel 5.8 Run PHP Artisan Command in Background while Clicking on a button from Blade View

Tags: laravel, queue, scheduler

I need to run a scheduler task from blade view by clicking a button (Sync) and it should go for process in the background.

I have created an artisan command that is php artisan projects:get and then I schedule it once a day for running in cron job, but in some case we need to run the cron job at user's choice so when he/she is in CMS logged in, they can click a sync button to run the cron job from there, but I think its not possible, but I knew there is some work around in Laravel to process the php artisan command which I already created that is projects:get using queues or process from symphony, but I know I can do it from the command line (terminal) using putty or cPanel terminal window, but As you know client can't login into cPanel and run the command so we need to give them just a simple button to click and sync in background, right now when user click that button, its getting delay and he/she can't continue to work on other things while its fetching all the projects from the API's that I used in that command. We need to queue/background process.

php artisan projects:get

Comment: you can run artisan commands from a job. take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands. However, you need to configure your queue worker and the job first.

Comment: For Job should we run some command once/only for first time and it will then look for any queued job in database and run it. Aur I have to run the jobs from php artisan command every time as we doing in localhost environment as we don't have any cron job things in xammp etc.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, you can run artisan commands from your php code as documented [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands)

Since the artisan command will likely take some time to execute, it is a good practice to use a [queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues) for this.

You said in the comments, that you are on xampp. On local, you need to run the `pap artisan queue:work` command once you started xampp. After you executed the command, the watcher will pick up jobs and will execute them. However, first you need to configure the queue. [This](https://laracasts.com/series/queue-it-up) will get you up and running. On a production server, you need to configure a supervisor to run the queue command.

Answer (score 0):

You can run artisan command programmtically like this:

**Route**

```
Route::get('/run/command', 'SomeController@runCommand');
```

**SomeController**

```
public function function()
{
    $exitCode = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('projects:get');
    return $exitCode;
}
```

Comment: I know about this, but here you can't send the process in background. This will stuck the user's current window and my php artisan command took around 3 minutes to complete so no one will wait for that long to perform the process. I think you didn't read my question completely.

Comment: @TahirAfridi I've read your question, you have to make ajax request for such purpose so that request will be executing in background.

Comment: This will still break my ajax request if someone leave the page by clicking other link or closing the browser/window/tab.

Comment: @SagarGautam did you get any solution? if so please share I also want to run command in the background even invoking through ajax but my ajax breaks

Comment: @WaqasShakeel You can create a job and put all logic inside the job handle method. When you click sync button, a job will be created and pushed to a queue and then job qill be executed in the background and we can send response to user immediately after pushing job to queue.

Comment: @SagarGautam Thank you yes I have sorted in same way.